# Changing permissions on user files for automating Apache VirtualHost creation

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-httpd

I currently have a small Ubuntu Server 12.04 machine (test environment) with about 3 non-root users created. Each user has their own `public_html` directory under their `home`...thereby allowing them to deploy multiple apps as named virtual hosts. Each user belongs to the Apache `www-data` group, set up as follows:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data [username]
sudo chown -R [username]:www-data /home/[username]/public_html
sudo chmod 2750 /home/[username]/public_html
```

Now as the root user, I am in the process of creating a bash script that will automate the creation of the folders for the VirtualHost under a prompted user's `public_html` as well as creating an associated entry in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. The script (run with `sudo`) will prompt for the user (`$uzer`) and the desired virtual host name (`$vhost`). So far after running a few checks I eventually get to the following...

```
mkdir -vp /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost
mkdir -vp /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost/www
mkdir -vp /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost/logs
mkdir -vp /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost/backups
```

I need to change the ownership of these newly created folders, so I'm unsure whether I should be doing the following:

```
chown -vR $uzer:www-data /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost
chmod 2750 /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost
```

My questions:

- Is my folder structure correct/ideal?
- I know I've used recursive (`-R`) option, but should I be repeating the same for `$vhost/www`, `$vhost/logs` and `$vhost/backups`?
- Am I correct in thinking that the chmod above is probably redundant?
- Is there a way I can run the `mkdir` commands as the user `$uzer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Q: Is my folder structure correct/ideal?

A: Folder structure seems fine.

#### Q: I know I've used recursive (-R) option, but should I be repeating the same for $vhost/www, $vhost/logs and $vhost/backups?

A: It would be redundant to run it on those directories

#### Q: Am I correct in thinking that the chmod above is probably redundant?

Yes technically it's redundant because your initial sudo that cretes the directories is setting the 'set group id bit', but setting that bit, (the 2 in 2750), is not a guarantee. I've seen directories with this on where users have either moved files into the directory or accidentally changed the group on files, so I'd leave it.

#### Is there a way I can run the mkdir commands as the user $uzer?

```
root$ su -u $user -c "mkdir ..."
```

Also you could save a step on the chmod of the /www, /log, & /backups by using the `mkdir --mode=...` switch.

#### For example

```
mkdir -vp --mode=2750 /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost
mkdir -vp --mode=2750 /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost/www
mkdir -vp --mode=2750 /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost/logs
mkdir -vp --mode=2750 /home/$uzer/public_html/$vhost/backups
```

Comment: slm, thank you for your response. Please could you elaborate on your last statement by saving a step on chmod. how would I use the `--mode` switch?

Comment: slm, thank you! You've given me solid feedback :)

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually if doesn't matter what folder structure you are using.
2. If you are using `-R` option in chown, it will only effect to the files and directories which are present at the time you are running the command.
3. No, because always you have to use `chmod` command to change the permission if you are making any changes manually.
4. You can ask `/etc/sudoers` file to allows $user to create any directory with `mkdir` command.

Comment: Thanks Nitesh! Let me try this out and I'll post back here

Comment: Regarding (3), My question of whether the `chmod` was redundant or not, is due to the fact that when the user is initially created the `sudo chmod 2750 /home/[username]/public_html` command *should* set the permissions for any new files/folders created under public_html to `750`...that's what the extra bit `2` is for I think

Comment: #4 is an extremely large security risk, allowing arbitrary code execution by that user.

Comment: @Chris: yup, you are right, its a large security risk, but google will help you for sure.